# Prove the existence of linear operator satisfying two particular conditions.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

> Let $K$ be  field and let $V$ be a $K$-vector space with finite dimension. Also let $T$ be a linear operator over $V$ such $T$ is not invertible and $T$ is not the zero operator. Prove the existence of two linear operators $G,H:V \to V$ both  not the zero operators and satisfying  $T\circ G=0$ and $H \circ T=0$.

I saw this problem in an admission test for a posgraduate program in mathematics and I found it kind of mystical since for being honest I don't know how to attack the problem. I mean $T$ being not invertible makes difficult the things also I cannot attack it with the diagonalization theory, spectral theory or another sub-theory in Linear Algebra. Can anyone guide me please how to attack this problem? :( Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $0 \neq \text{Im}(T) \neq V$ and $0 \neq \text{ker}(T) \neq V$.

Comment: @Demophilus My idea for $G:V \to V$ is $G(v)=v$ if $v \in Ker(T)$ and $G(v)=0$ if $v \notin Ker(T)$ so this way the linear operator $G$ happens to be $G \neq 0$ and $T \circ G=0$, this is well defined linear transformation? I am not sure at all. Any other hint defining $H$? :)

Comment: @Demophilus For $H:V \to V$ im just thinking of random linear operator $H$ with the extra condition of $H(v)=0$ if $v \in Im(T)$, does this work?

Comment: That's precisely what I was thinking, as you can see in my answer.

Comment: @Demophilus Nice! What about my idea for the operator $G$? Im not pretty sure it is a linear transformation :P

Comment: Correct as well. An easy way to verify it is linear is by considering a basis for $\text{Ker}(T)$ and then adding vectors from $V$ until it becomes a basis for the entire $V$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67680/discussion-between-cos-and-demophilus).

Answer (score 0):

Some more hints:
Clearly $H(T(v))=0$ for all $v$, so $H$ restricted to $\text{Im}(H)$ should be zero. Now define $H(v)$ for any $v \not \in \text{Im}(H)$ in such a way that $H \neq 0$.